# Displaying images/icons besides y-axis in Flex Bar charts

Tags: apache-flex, charts, categories, customization

I am trying to place an image besides the label in y-axis. So I have created a custom label renderer(A HBox containing  and ). The source for the image has to be set based on a property present in the data provider. The problem is, I am not able to access the BarSeriesItem in the fnSetSource() method. Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated.
Here's the entire code.

```
 <mx:Application  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
        layout="vertical"
        width="1280" height="750">  
  <mx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.charts.series.items.PlotSeriesItem;
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.controls.Image;
    import mx.containers.HBox;
    import mx.charts.series.items.BarSeriesItem;
    import mx.charts.series.ColumnSeries;
    import mx.charts.series.items.ColumnSeriesItem;
    import mx.charts.chartClasses.Series;
    import mx.charts.ChartItem;
    [Bindable]
public var employeedetails:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([              
{rank:"10",emplName:"Peter",prevRank:"7",imgSource:"images/increase.png"},
{rank:"9",emplName:"Mark",prevRank:"3",imgSource:"images/decrease.png"},
{rank:"8",emplName:"Eric",prevRank:"8",imgSource:"images/decrease.png"}


]);
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>    


    <mx:BarChart id="bar" height="100%"  
            paddingLeft="15" paddingRight="5" 
            showDataTips="true"  width="847" 
            dataTipMode="multiple" >
            <mx:verticalAxis>
                <mx:CategoryAxis id="v1" categoryField="emplName" dataProvider="{employeedetails}"/>
            </mx:verticalAxis>

            <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
                <mx:AxisRenderer placement="left" axis="{v1}">
                    <mx:labelRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="120" minHeight="20">
                                <mx:Image id="axisImage" height="16" width="16" source="fnSetSource()">
                                    <mx:Script><![CDATA[
                                        import mx.charts.chartClasses.Series;
                                        import mx.charts.ChartItem;
                                        import mx.charts.series.items.BarSeriesItem;                                        
                                        [Bindable]
                                        public function fnSetSource(element : ChartItem, series : Series) : String
                                        {
                                        var data : BarSeriesItem = BarSeriesItem(element);
                                        var imgSrc : String = "";
                                        if (data.item.isIncrease)
                                        {
                                        imgSrc = "images/increase.png";
                                        } else if (data.item.isDecrease)
                                        {
                                        imgSrc = "images/decrease.png";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        imgSrc = "";
                                        }
                                        return imgSrc;
                                        }
                                    ]]></mx:Script>
                                </mx:Image>
                                <mx:Label id="axisLabel" fontSize="12" width="100%" height="100%">
                                    <mx:Script><![CDATA[
                                        [Bindable]
                                        override public function set data(value : Object) : void
                                            {
                                            if (value == null)
                                            {
                                                return;
                                            }
                                            var length : int = value.text.toString().length;
                                            if (length > 15)
                                            {
                                                axisLabel.text = value.text.toString().substr(0, 15) + "...";
                                                axisLabel.toolTip = value.text;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                axisLabel.text = value.text;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]]>
                                    </mx:Script>
                                </mx:Label>
                            </mx:HBox>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:labelRenderer>
                </mx:AxisRenderer>
            </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
            <mx:series>
                <mx:BarSeries id="bs2"
                yField="emplName" 
                xField="rank" 
                displayName="Rank"    
                dataProvider="{employeedetails}"                                 
                />          
        </mx:series>
    </mx:BarChart>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Kindly use the code at [link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_03.html) and replace the dataprovider with public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {Month:"Jan", Profit:2000, Expenses:1500,isIncrease:true},
        {Month:"Feb", Profit:1000, Expenses:200,isDecrease:false},
        {Month:"Mar", Profit:1500, Expenses:500,isIncrease:true}
     ]);
   If isIncrease is set to true, need to place an icon next to month in y-axis.If it is set to false, need to place a different icon.Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Brian, I have edited the original question and have given the entire code. The problem is: in fnSetSource(), am trying to set the source of images, but they are coming as blank. Please help. Am I doing the right thing or cant we get the value in chart data item in axis renderer?

Comment: When you set categoryField="emplName" in categoryaxis, what does the property 'data' refer to corresponding axisrenderer?Is it just the value in emplName or the entire object in the data provider?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Would like to know how if you did pls

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the code. The fnSetSource() function will not be called until it is placed inside curly brackets: source="{fnSetSource()}"

This will get the function to be called, but you will get errors because the fnSetSource() call does not have the 2 parameters that fnSetSource function requires. Make the first change I mentioned and you may be able to figure it out from there.

Could you not make an item renderer that is a seperate mxml component?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the belated response. I have got the functionality through a different approach . posting it here thinking it would be useful to somebody.create a custom component FormItemWithImage which extends form item. In this component an image can be added in creatChildren method.Source of the image and the text of the label will be supplied from the mxml. It works absolutely fine. Thank you very  much for all your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

look like you are not passing any parameters that fnSetSource() needs so it will not work untill you pass those two parameters..
use your function this way
fnSetSource(value:Object,previousValue:Object,axis:IAxis):String